# Most Reliable Audio Gear Resources?

Tags: gear, consumer

Purchasing audio gear is obviously a huge deal. It requires a lot of research because you will most likely be stuck with the thing for a long time. But finding reliable resources can be as difficult as actually buying the thing itself.

Because stack sites don't generally seem suitable for consumer-related advice, I was wondering if some savvy individuals might have good tips on "reliable" consumer resources.  You know, like some real neat forum with very authentic audio engineering types who cut through the nonsense and tell you the good stuff that's the good value.  Such types are of course friendly and accessible and discuss the finer (although not too fine) points of what makes a thing good technically, and what is most likely an over-marketed mediocre product (beats headphones being the now classic example).

What think you?

Edit: I'm not talking about stereos.  I'm talking about stuff you make stuff with. There's a reason I posted this question in sound design.

Comment: Are you talking consumer level audio production gear (such as cheap mixers and audio interfaces) or consumer hi-fi (like hi-fi speakers, receivers, etc).  The two are vastly different questions and the former is on topic but the later is off topic.  In the case of the former, if you have a question about a particular item, you can try asking it here as well.  We entertain questions comparing specific items if the items are sound design/mixing/recording/production related.

Comment: The term consumer is somewhat ambiguous. I do not mean to make a distinction between consumer and professional per se. I mean consumer as a person buying stuff whether amateur, professional, pro-sumer, etc. The question is more aimed to address the reliability of resources for making purchasing decisions.  

But I do mean makers of sound versus listeners of sound.  In other words, a good resource for making informed and honest decisions about purchasing gear such as audio interfaces, mixing and mastering monitors, synthesizers, mics, etc etc...

Comment: sorry, missed that.  I've sadly been without a desktop and have had to try reviewing stuff from my phone the last few days since I just moved.  Unfortunately, we do get a lot of consumer/hi-fi questions asked here by new users, which is why you got some resistance initially.  It seems you did your homework though and now that you've clarified in the main question, I have re-opened it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend gearslutz.com. Absolutely amazing place to ask questions regarding audio gear. Also, if at all you are on facebook, you would want to join Pensado's Students. Its a group dedicated to audio. You can drop in any questions over there and you will get a guaranteed reply in a few minutes.